# Gravity form to submit to third party application

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I would like to know what the cleanest way to use gravity forms to submit data from my form to another page outside of WordPress is.
Our website is 100% WordPress and I need to use data of my gravity form somewhere else.

I found [this blog article](http://www.0to5blog.com/creative/gravity-forms-submitting-forms-to-3rd-party-applications/), that seems to provide a solution, but I really would like to avoid modifying
`/wp-content/themes/*your-theme*/functions.php`

I am worried about losing the changes at a WordPress / gravity forms update.

Comment: The link pretty much provides you with your answer. Editing the functions.php file of your theme is not as bad as it sounds and is the way to add custom functionality to your site without editing Wordpress or plugin core files which is a BIG no no.

Comment: Thanks Nicole, during wordpress standard update there is no change on this file so ?

Comment: The functions.php file is not really a core file and is part of your theme. So when Wordpress updates it does not touch those files.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the `functions.php` file of your theme is not as bad as it sounds.

The article I had found detailed the right solution.

The `functions.php` file is not a WP core file, but part of your theme.
So when WordPress updates itself, it does not touch those files.

When the plugin is updated, it doesn't affect these either.

Comment: But when the theme is updated it does get overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as a functions plugin:

http://www.doitwithwp.com/create-functions-plugin/

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/02/02/creating-a-custom-functions-plugin-for-end-users

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WordPress [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). It's easy to do with the [One-click Child Theme plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/one-click-child-theme/). That way, even when you update your theme, you don't overwrite the changes you've made in `functions.php`

Comment: This is barely more than a link-only answer. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Create a WordPress child theme using the plugin mentioned and then add a clean `functions.php` file to that.

The link you gave doesn't work with the latest GF so use the [example on the GF site](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission).